# SuiteCRM populate related fields

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm, auto-populate

On Opportunity module edit view, when choosing Contact (related field) I need to auto populate Account Name (related field).
I can fill in Contact and Account Name edit boxes and only one id.
It means I can set Contact or Account Name, but not booth of them.

Anyone can help?

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'kontakt_c',
        'studio' => 'visible',
        'label' => 'LBL_KONTAKT',
        'displayParams' => array (
            'field_to_name_array' => array(     
                'id' => 'contact_id_c', 
                'name' => 'kontakt_c',
                'account_name' => 'account_name',
                'account_id' => 'account_id',
                ),
         ),
      ),
      1 => 
        array (
            'name' => 'account_name',
            'studio' => 'visible',
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with custom views, introducing there any javascript code you might need.

First you build the custom view in custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php';

class CustomContactsViewEdit extends ContactsViewEdit
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->useForSubpanel = true;
        $this->useModuleQuickCreateTemplate = true;
        // Since the suite base modules name the bean in the singular, we configure in the view the name of the module in the plural. This property will be used by the SticViews class to load the language files
        $this->moduleName = 'Contacts';
    }

    public function preDisplay()
    {
        parent::preDisplay();


        // Write here you custom code
    }

    public function display()
    {
        parent::display();

        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/Contacts/CustomUtils.js"></script>';
    }
}
```

Then you build your javascript file custom/modules/Contacts/CustomUtils.js introducing code you might need.

If you don't need it to be immediate, you can also use a Logic Hook before_save and assign the Account/Contact there respectively.